# Generar clave con listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escribi el siguiente codigo, funcion por funcion. El objetivo de este es generar una clave compuesta de la siguiente forma:
El primer carácter será el número que represente la cantidad de números 3
(tres) que aparezcan en la historia clínica. Si dicho número es 0 (cero), el
carácter será un @.
El segundo carácter será el último número de la historia clínica.
La última parte será la suma del 3er y 4to número (puede ser más de un
carácter).
Tengo el siguiente problema, si ingreso los números de a uno, el código funciona perfectamente (ya lo comprobé) pero si lo intento hacer correr con una lista de números, el código me da error. No logro encontrar el error, les dejo el código entero para ver si pueden encontrar el error que yo no encuentro. Antes que eso le dejo un ejemplo, para que vean como tendría que ser. Por ejemplo el usuario ingresa su numero Historial clínico n:6704430, la clave que le tiene que devolver el programa es: 104. Si yo ingreso este numero solo, el programa corre. Pero si le ingreso una lista de esta forma

> SA = [6704430, 9219120, 6732330, 6932190, 6732340]
> ya tira error.
> El codigo que hice es el siguiente:

```
def cantAparicionesTres (histClin):
    cantidad=0
    for pos in range (len(histClin)):
      if histClin[pos]=="3":
            cantidad+=1
    if cantidad==0:
        cantidad="@"
    return cantidad


def ultimoCaracter(histClin):
    ultimo= histClin[-1]
    return ultimo

def suma(histClin):
    tercera = histClin[2]
    cuarta=  histClin[3]
    sumaFinal= int(tercera)+int(cuarta)
    return sumaFinal


def generar_clave(histClin):
    clave=cantAparicionesTres(histClin)+ultimoCaracter(histClin)+suma(histClin)
    return clave

SA = [6704430, 9219120, 6732330, 6932190, 6732340]

print(generar_clave(SA))
```

Comment: creo que se debe a que el programa toma `len(histClin)` como la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array que le pasas, ya que en ningun momento recorres el array que pasas como parametro para obtener su valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije el problema es por que no recorres la lista que le pasas, y de ahi se genera el error, esto se soluciona con un pequeño if en la funcion y arreglando algunas cosas al momento de retornar el valor.

**Funcion general**

```py
def generar_clave(histClin):
   if type(histClin) is list: #verificamos si es una lista
       for hist in histClin:  #recorremos la lista
            #las funciones esperan un string
            #por eso lo convertimos con str()
            clave=cantAparicionesTres(str(hist))+ultimoCaracter(str(hist))+suma(str(hist))
            print(clave)
   else:
        print("holas")
        clave=cantAparicionesTres(histClin)+ultimoCaracter(histClin)+suma(histClin)
   return clave
```

**Demas Funciones**

```
def suma(histClin):
    ...
    return str(sumaFinal) #retornamos como string
```

```
def cantAparicionesTres (histClin):
    histClin = str(histClin) # cambiamos su valor a string para recorrelo
    return str(cantidad)     #retornamos como string
```

Esos son los cambios necesario, y listo, funcionara, si tienes algun problema dejamelo saber.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: @gaston si la respuesta te ayudo aceptala